# Insert win32_PhysicalMemory PowerShell data into SQL Server table

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012, windows-10, windows-7-x64

I am trying to insert all the data from Get-WmiObject win32_PhysicalMemory PowerShell code into SQL Server 2012:

> ```
> $MemoryObjects = Get-WmiObject win32_PhysicalMemory  
> foreach($i in
> $MemoryObjects) {  
> $Sn = $computerBIOS.SerialNumber
> $Item = @{label=$_.Label}
> $Des = $_.Description
>  $InsertQuery=" INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable]
>         ([SerialNumber]
>         ,[Item]
>         ,[Value])
>         VALUES
>         ('$Sn'
>         ,'$Item'
>         ,'$Des')
>         GO
>         "
> Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance 'ServerName' -query $insertquery -U Username -P 'Password' -Database MyDB  }
> ```

The code only inserts the serial number, it does not insert the label and its value. Any suggestion on how to do that? For each memory module, there are around 40 values, some of them are shown in the picture below.
My SQL Server table has three columns (all varchar datatype). The first column is for the serial number, the second is for the label and the last one for the value. I am not sure how the last two columns.

[image]

Comment: why are you using `$_` in a `foreach` loop? [*grin*] that is for the pipeline ... you otta be using the "current loop item variable" that you  defined - the `$i`.

Comment: also, there is no `.Label` property on my memory ... only a `.BankLabel`.

Comment: Why you query the `$Item = @{label=$_.Label}` if there is no property named **Label**?

Comment: I am not sure how to access the properties and save them in the table. I tried the $i variable, but it stores "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData" in the table.